# Proving $\lim\frac1{x_n} = -\infty$ if $\lim x_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $x_n < 0$ for all $n$.
If $\lim x_n = 0$, prove that $\lim\frac1{x_n} = -\infty$.

Comment: Try \forall and \exists (both in math mode, within \$ delimiters). Greek letters, same way -- such as \alpha (also in math mode): $\forall\exists\alpha$

Comment: It's not HTML, it's MathJaX (almost identical to LaTeX, if you use it). There's a good tutorial here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This seems like it would be quite difficult to prove... you might even need to go back to the definition of a real number, or the real number axioms.

Comment: @JackM: I don't think so. The definition of limit should be enough.

Comment: @rubik I guess it depends what you call a proof. The current answer, for instance, doesn't justify that $a<b\implies1/a>1/b$. This is fine, but I suppose I was implicitly assuming that if you're going to prove something this basic, you may as well go all out. Otherwise it seems a bit like "proving" that $3+2=2+3$ by saying "$\mathbb Z$ is an abelian group under addition". I suppose the question was just an exercice in understanding the definition of a limit, though, so the current answer is probably what was intended.

Comment: @JackM: Now I understand what you are saying, and I agree.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $M < 0$. Since $x_n \to 0$, there exists an index $N$ for which $n \ge N$ implies $\dfrac 1M < x_n < 0$. In turn you have that $n \ge N$ implies $\dfrac{1}{x_n} < M$. This is precisely the definition of $\dfrac 1{x_n} \to -\infty$.